# sed: can't read, invalid sigil

Tags: bash, sed

At my work we have remote Windows desktop for Ubuntu users (me). The connection was fine until today I arrived at work. When I tried to run `./agenda.sh` command in terminal, I got this error:

```
sed: can't read /cert:tofu: No such file or directory
sed: can't read /v:HOST_CONN: No such file or directory
[07:13:50:713] [6890:6890] [ERROR][com.winpr.commandline] - Failed at index 1 [/size:1800x950]: Invalid sigil
```

**agenda.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash
unset http_proxy
unset https_proxy
unset HTTP_PROXY
unset HTTPS_PROXY
xfreerdp /size:"1800x950" /u:"user" /d:company /p:grep pass ~/.mad | sed "s/.*=//" /cert:tofu /v:HOST_CONN
```

Anyone got a hint? As I said before, it worked 12 hours ago...

Comment: As you can see from the code your posted, the `sed` command is supposed to process a file named `/cert:tofu` , and this file does not exist. This should be pretty clear. Just fix the script. BTW, if you are going to explicitly specify a file by name, **and** also want to process stdin, you need (at least in Gnu sed) represent the stdin in the file name list by a lone dash (`-`).

Comment: The last line in the script doesn't make sense. It pipes the output from the `xfreerdp` command to a `sed` command that doesn't read from that input; instead, it reads from `/cert:tofu`  and `/v:HOST_CONN`, neither of which looks like an actual filepath (are they supposed to be options to some other program, like maybe `xfreerdp`?). I don't see how this *could* have worked 12 hours ago, or at any other time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone has edited this command, perhaps in an attempt to set the password from a value stored in a file:

```
xfreerdp /size:"1800x950" /u:"user" /d:company /p:grep pass ~/.mad | sed "s/.*=//" /cert:tofu /v:HOST_CONN
```

I would guess it is supposed to be more like:

```
xfreerdp /size:"1800x950" /u:"user" /d:company /p:"$(grep pass ~/.mad | sed "s/.*=//")" /cert:tofu /v:HOST_CONN
```

Comment: Your command fixed it, but I still dont understand why it worked everyday until today. Thanks anyway!